Thermal hall effect in a system with an anyon
I am trying to understand what happens to the thermal hall effect of a fractional quantum hall system when there is a nontrivial anyonic charge in the bulk. I have two calculations which seem to disagree with each other:
First, following https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0111437, the thermal current at the edge is given by
$$J_Q = \left\langle T-\bar{T}\right\rangle_T$$
where $v$ is the velocity, and $T$ is the holomorphic stress-energy tensor of the edge CFT. In the paper they then calculate the expectation of $T$ on a cylinder by
$$\left\langle T_{cyl}(w)\right\rangle=\left\langle T_{plane}(z)\right\rangle \left(\frac{dz}{dw}\right)+\frac{c}{12} \{ z,w \}$$
where the plane coordinate $z=x+iy$ is related to the cylinder coordinate $w=v\tau+ix$ via
$$z=\exp\left[\frac{2\pi i(v\tau+ix)}{v\beta}\right]$$
When there is no defect through the cylinder the expectation of the first term vanishes. Where there is, I am calculating it via
$$\left\langle \phi|T_{plane}(z)|\phi\right\rangle=\frac{1}{z^2}h$$
with $h$ being the scaling dimension of the field $\phi$. Overall, this gives the value (in the leading order in the length $L$ of the system):
$$\left\langle T_{cyl}(w)\right\rangle=\frac{\pi^2 c}{6v^2\beta^2}-\frac{4\pi^2 h}{v^2\beta^2}$$
which translates to the thermal current ($t$ being the temperature)
$$J_Q=\frac{\pi}{12}t^2(c-\bar{c})-2\pi t^2(h-\bar{h}).$$
In particular, it seems like the bulk anyon gives a universal contribution to the thermal hall effect.
On the other hand, I tried calculating it in the particular case of the edge theory being free fermions. There it is possible to do the calculation directly by summing over the modes. The existence of a bulk anyon (a twist field with $(h,\bar{h})=(\frac{1}{16},0)$ I believe) corresponds in that case to anti-periodic boundary conditions of the fermionic edge modes. The energy of each mode is given by (up to a constant)
$E_n =\frac{v}{L}(n+\gamma)$ where $\gamma=1/2$ where there is an anyon in the bulk and $0$ otherwise, and $n$ are summed for $n\ge 0$. The thermal current at the edge is then given by
$$J_Q=\sum_n \frac{v}{L}(n+\gamma)\frac{e^{-\frac{v}{LT}(n+\gamma)}}{1+e^{-\frac{v}{LT}(n+\gamma)}}.$$
The sum can be evaluated by integration in the limit of large $L$, with the leading-order answer being independent of $\gamma$. Intuitively this makes sense: the large $L$ limit sums over many modes, and the $\gamma$ contribution should be sub leading.
It seems though that the two calculations yield a contradicting result as to whether the bulk anyon has a contribution to the current. What am I missing? I assume this calculation exist somewhere, but I haven't managed to find it, so any relevant reference would be welcome.
